# Opening .jpg files in R: can you only open JPEG files if the file lies in an R packages?

Tags: r, jpeg, package

I noticed that if you are trying to use "system.file()" to source the image for "readJPEG()", then you have to include a package name in order to open the image. But what if I wanted to open a .jpg file from say, my pictures folder? Is this possible? Is R only able to open images using system.file() to source .jpg files?

Answer (score 1):

install `jpeg` library and load it and then call `readJPEG` function with the .jpg file.

```
library('jpeg')
myjpeg_array <- jpeg::readJPEG(source = "myjpeg.jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you! do you know how big the file would be before it could no longer be printed/ plotted in R?

Comment: Also, how would the file be plotted? I used the following, but it is not working. instead, it only shows me a picture of the R logo in the console when i run this code: myjpeg_array
plot(0:1, 0:1, type = "n", ann =FALSE, axes = FALSE)
rasterImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1) @Sathish

Comment: Look at the help page of image: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/image.html